# Get filename with dots included in bash string

Tags: bash

I created an aliases for bash to convert markdown to pdf using pandoc.
Is working as I expected except the situation when a file has some dots in filename.
I want to manipulate string in order to get the exact filename in output.

```bash
cpandoc ()
 {
 pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex --citeproc "$1" -o "${1%%.*}.pdf"
 }
```

running for example `cpandoc '5.2. Section.md'` the output is `5.pdf`

Comment: `${var%%pattern}` with the double percent-sign removes the _longest_ matching suffix, so starting at the first dot here. With one `%`, it takes the shortest match, and that's probably what you want. So `"${1%.*}"`

Comment: (well, as long as you don't have filenames like `foo.txt.gz` where you want to remove the whole `.txt.gz`)

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks a lot. Is working now !